how can i make my code run after user dials a ussd code
I have been practicing how I can implement my program to work after a user requests an ussd code from a service provider. I have been working on a personal project that will provide medical information to local people on a network on how they can access health information without needing to meet a health officer.
package medicationinfo;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MedicationInfo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice;

        ArrayList<String> diseases = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("CHOOSE THE DISEASE YOU WANT TO KNOW MORE ABOUT\n\n" + "1. Malaria\n" + "2. Respiratory Infections\n" + "3. Diarrheal Diseases\n " + "4. Malnutrition\n" + 
                "5. HIV/AIDS\n" + "6. Measles\n" + "7. Meningitis\n" + "8. Tuberculosis\n" + 
                "9. Schistosomiasis\n" + "10. Neglected Tropical Disease (NTD's"));
        //System.out.println("Select a disease:");
        //System.out.println("1. Malaria");
       // System.out.println("2. Respiratory Infections");
       // System.out.println("3. Diarrheal Diseases");
       // System.out.println("4. Malnutrition");
       // System.out.println("5. HIV/AIDS");
       // System.out.println("6. Measles");
        //System.out.println("7. Meningitis");
        //System.out.println("8. Tuberculosis (TB)");
       // System.out.println("9. Schistosomiasis");
       // System.out.println("10. Neglected Tropical Diseases (NTDs)");
       // System.out.println("0. Exit");
       System.out.println(diseases);
        System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
        choice = scanner.nextInt();

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:

                //System.out.println("MALARIA");
                System.out.println(diseases.get(1));

                System.out.println("1. Prevention");
                System.out.println("2. Symptoms");
                System.out.println("3. Treatement");
                System.out.print("Choose what you want to know about MALARIA: ");
                choice = scanner.nextInt();
                switch (choice) {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("PREVENTION"); // ways of preventing malaria
                        System.out.println("Use insectcides");
                        System.out.println("Use bed nets");
                        System.out.println("Indoor residual spraying");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("SYMPTOMS"); // symptoms of malaria
                        System.out.println("fever");
                        System.out.println("Chills");
                        System.out.println("Sweating");
                        System.out.println("Headaches");
                        System.out.println("Nausea vomit");
                        System.out.println("Bodyaches");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("TREATMENT"); // treatment of malaria
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("EXIT");
            
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("Respiratory Infections");
                System.out.println("1. Prevention");
                System.out.println("2. Symptoms");
                System.out.println("3. Treatement");
                choice = scanner.nextInt();
                switch (choice) {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("PREVENTION");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("SYMPTOMS");
                        System.out.println("sudden high fever");
                        System.out.println("severe headache");
                        System.out.println("stiff neck");
                        System.out.println("nausea and vomiting");
                        System.out.println("sensitivity to light");
                        System.out.println("confusion or altered consiousness");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("TREATMENT");
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("EXIT");
                }
                break;

I have just provided a little from the code I wrote, so I need help on how I can go about implementing an ussd utilization.
I also tried to put the diseases into an ArrayList, but whenever I call the List specifying the index I want to be printed, it says IndexOutOfBoundsException. here I replaced the code
    //System.out.println("Select a disease:");
        //System.out.println("1. Malaria");
       // System.out.println("2. Respiratory Infections");
       // System.out.println("3. Diarrheal Diseases");
       // System.out.println("4. Malnutrition");
       // System.out.println("5. HIV/AIDS");
       // System.out.println("6. Measles");
        //System.out.println("7. Meningitis");
        //System.out.println("8. Tuberculosis (TB)");
       // System.out.println("9. Schistosomiasis");
       // System.out.println("10. Neglected Tropical Diseases (NTDs)");
       // System.out.println("0. Exit");

with
     ArrayList<String> diseases = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("CHOOSE THE DISEASE YOU WANT TO KNOW MORE ABOUT\n\n" + "1. Malaria\n" + "2. Respiratory Infections\n" + "3. Diarrheal Diseases\n " + "4. Malnutrition\n" + 
                "5. HIV/AIDS\n" + "6. Measles\n" + "7. Meningitis\n" + "8. Tuberculosis\n" + 
                "9. Schistosomiasis\n" + "10. Neglected Tropical Disease (NTD's"));

and called it here
    System.out.println(diseases.get(1));

 


but whenever i call the List specifying the index i want to be printed, it says indexoutofbounce

The reason why your code is throwing an IndexOutOfBoundsException is because you haven't actually created a List of 11 options, but a List with a single string in position 0, which is a concatenation of all the options.
This is why diseases.get(1) is throwing an exception, because you're trying to index a second element in position 1 that doesn't exist.
If you want to create a List with 11 options, you should separate each String with a comma and not a plus sign. Like so:
List<String> diseases = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
    "CHOOSE THE DISEASE YOU WANT TO KNOW MORE ABOUT\n",
    "1. Malaria",
    "2. Respiratory Infections",
    "3. Diarrheal Diseases",
    "4. Malnutrition",
    "5. HIV/AIDS",
    "6. Measles",
    "7. Meningitis",
    "8. Tuberculosis",
    "9. Schistosomiasis",
    "10. Neglected Tropical Disease (NTD's)"));

Here is a tweaked version of your code:
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice;

        List<String> diseases = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                "CHOOSE THE DISEASE YOU WANT TO KNOW MORE ABOUT\n",
                "1. Malaria",
                "2. Respiratory Infections",
                "3. Diarrheal Diseases",
                "4. Malnutrition",
                "5. HIV/AIDS",
                "6. Measles",
                "7. Meningitis",
                "8. Tuberculosis",
                "9. Schistosomiasis",
                "10. Neglected Tropical Disease (NTD's)"));

        diseases.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.print("\nEnter your choice: ");
        choice = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine(); //gets rid of line terminator for your next read

        System.out.println(diseases.get(choice));

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                //...
                break;

            case 2:
                //...
                break;

            //case ...

            default:
                //....
        }
    }
}

Side Note on Scanner
Whenever you're reading a data type that is not String with the Scanner class, for example with a nextInt(), you should follow that call with a nextLine(). This is to get rid of the line terminator following the number you've entered, in your case the menu choice.
Without including that extra nextLine(), the following nextInt() will be immediately halted as a white space is encountered right away, stopping the read of the int value. In fact, nextInt() continues to read as long as the inputted texts matches a regex for integer values. Since there is a white space (a new line) the read stops immediately. See javadoc

If the translation is successful, the scanner advances past the input that matched. If the next token matches the Integer regular expression defined above then the token is converted into an int value as if by removing all locale specific prefixes, group separators, and locale specific suffixes, [...]

References

Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?
https://www.baeldung.com/java-scanner-integer#linebreak-handling


Should be: List<String> diseases = new ArrayList<>(...)

Also, why convert the immutable List.of immediately into an mutable ArrayList?

@Mr.Polywhirl yeah, it was like that because I copied it from OP and I tried to keep it as original as possible. But thanks for the edit.

@Mr.Polywhirl this is for your second comment. Again, I didn't want to change too much about OP's original code, but just address their main issue.

You can make your application data-driven. Store all your JSON data in a file and request data from it.
{
  "diseases": [
    {
      "name": "Malaria",
      "preventions": [
        "Use insecticides",
        "Use bed nets",
        "Indoor residual spraying"
      ],
      "symptoms": [
        "Fever",
        "Chills",
        "Sweating",
        "Headaches",
        "Nausea vomit",
        "Body Aches"
      ],
      "treatments": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Respiratory Infections",
      "preventions": [],
      "symptoms": [
        "Sudden high fever",
        "Severe headache",
        "Stiff neck",
        "Nausea and vomiting",
        "Sensitivity to light",
        "Confusion or altered consciousness"
      ],
      "treatments": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Diarrheal Diseases",
      "preventions": [],
      "symptoms": [],
      "treatments": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Malnutrition",
      "preventions": [],
      "symptoms": [],
      "treatments": []
    },
    {
      "name": "HIV/AIDS",
      "preventions": [],
      "symptoms": [],
      "treatments": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Measles",
      "preventions": [],
      "symptoms": [],
      "treatments": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Meningitis",
      "preventions": [],
      "symptoms": [],
      "treatments": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Tuberculosis",
      "preventions": [],
      "symptoms": [],
      "treatments": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Schistosomiasis",
      "preventions": [],
      "symptoms": [],
      "treatments": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Neglected Tropical Disease (NTDs)",
      "preventions": [],
      "symptoms": [],
      "treatments": []
    }
  ]
}

Now that you have well-structured JSON, you can create some models the represent it:
record Disease(String name, String[] preventions, String[] treatments, String[] symptoms) {}

record MedicalData(Disease[] diseases) {}

You can use Jackson to parse the JSON resource:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>

InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("data.json");
MedicalData medicalData = medicalData = objectMapper.readValue(is, MedicalData.class);


Demo
Putting it all together:
package org.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class MedicationInfoApp {
    private static final ClassLoader classLoader = MedicationInfoApp.class.getClassLoader();
    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    private final MedicalData medicalData;

    public MedicationInfoApp() {
        try {
            // Load data
            this.medicalData = objectMapper.readValue(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("data.json"), MedicalData.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        MedicationInfoApp app = new MedicationInfoApp();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean isRunning = true;
        int choice;

        while (isRunning) {
            app.printMainMenu();

            System.out.print(">>> ");
            choice = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
            scanner.nextLine(); // Clear line

            if (choice == -1) {
                System.out.println("Goodbye");
                isRunning = false;
                continue;
            }

            Optional<Disease> disease = app.getDisease(choice);

            if (disease.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.printf("Invalid option: %d%n", choice);
                continue;
            }

            app.printSubMenu(disease.get().name);
            choice = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine(); // Clear line
            app.printDetails(disease.get(), choice);
        }
    }

    public void printMainMenu() {
        System.out.println("\nChoose a disease you want to know more about:");
        for (int i = 0; i < medicalData.diseases.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%2d. %s%n", i + 1, medicalData.diseases[i].name);
        }
        System.out.printf("%2d. %s%n", 0, "Exit");
    }

    private void printDetails(Disease disease, int choice) {
        switch (choice) {
            case 1 -> {
                System.out.println("Prevention:");
                System.out.println(formatList(disease.preventions));
            }
            case 2 -> {
                System.out.println("Symptoms:");
                System.out.println(formatList(disease.symptoms));
            }
            case 3 -> {
                System.out.println("Treatments:");
                System.out.println(formatList(disease.treatments));
            }
            default -> {
                System.out.printf("Invalid choice: %d%n", choice);
            }
        }
    }

    private String formatList(String... values) {
        return Stream.of(values).map(v -> String.format("- %s", v)).collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
    }

    private void printSubMenu(String name) {
        System.out.println("1. Prevention");
        System.out.println("2. Symptoms");
        System.out.println("3. Treatment");
        System.out.printf("Choose what you want to know about %s: ", name);
    }

    private Optional<Disease> getDisease(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= medicalData.diseases.length) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        return Optional.of(medicalData.diseases[index]);
    }

    private record Disease(String name, String[] preventions, String[] treatments, String[] symptoms) {}

    private record MedicalData(Disease[] diseases) {}
}

Running the application will greet you with the first menu:
Choose a disease you want to know more about:
 1. Malaria
 2. Respiratory Infections
 3. Diarrheal Diseases
 4. Malnutrition
 5. HIV/AIDS
 6. Measles
 7. Meningitis
 8. Tuberculosis
 9. Schistosomiasis
10. Neglected Tropical Disease (NTDs)
 0. Exit
>>>

After choosing an option, you can get output such as:
>> 1
1. Prevention
2. Symptoms
3. Treatment
Choose what you want to know about Malaria: 2
Symptoms:
- Fever
- Chills
- Sweating
- Headaches
- Nausea vomit
- Body Aches

